# Update Textclock when changing locale

Tags: android, locale, date-format

I'm using a textClock widget in my app layout. I must support different languages, and add dateformat must be full date like "EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss a". The problem is that the days name and Months stays always with the default locale. When I change locale programatically it does not change.

Any suggestion?
Shouldn't this be handled automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont't work with the default widget. So I used my Own class and its working as expected. You just have to make sure to change your locale in the right way.

```
   public class MyTextClock extends android.widget.TextClock {


    public MyTextClock(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setLocaleDateFormat();
    }

    public MyTextClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setLocaleDateFormat();
    }

    public MyTextClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setLocaleDateFormat();
    }

    private void setLocaleDateFormat()
    {
        Locale currentLocale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
        Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), currentLocale);

        String dayName = cal.getDisplayName(cal.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, currentLocale);
        String monthName =cal.getDisplayName(cal.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, currentLocale);

        this.setFormat12Hour("'"+dayName+"' '"+monthName+"' dd, yyyy h:m:ss a");
        this.setFormat24Hour("'"+dayName+"', dd '"+monthName+"' yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this using [`public void setTextLocale (Locale locale)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextLocale(java.util.Locale)):

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
// Change locale settings in the app.
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale(language_code.toLowerCase());
yourTextClock.setTextLocale(conf.locale);
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. Some how, it works partially. Im using in portuguese, when I change language to english, it changes the format to the english format 12Hour, but days and names keep in portuguese. It's kind of weird..:S

Comment: I've updated the solution with some code that should work. Try and tell me if it's useful please

Comment: Thanks Andreu, but I got same result. It changes the format of the Date but Days and Month names stays with the locale of the tablet.

Comment: Okay I'll keep looking. If you find some solution please post it :)

Comment: Ok then. If you find something share it please. I'll keep looking for more info

Comment: I think I found the problem. In **TexClock** class, DateText is changed using  `setText(DateFormat.format(mFormat, mTime));` but if you look in to the DateFormat source. in static method `format` you find  `LocaleData localeData = LocaleData.get(Locale.getDefault());` It looks that this widget will only take change on the default locale change. :S

Comment: You'll have to make your own `TextClock` overriding this part of code

Answer (score 0):

I removed format12Hour or format24Hour attributes from xml and updated my code just like this

```
digitalClock = view.findViewById(R.id.my_id);
textClock.setFormat12Hour("EEE, MMM dd");
textClock.setFormat24Hour("EEE, MMM dd");
```

after changing languages it works fine